# How do you generalize a filepath in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, filepath

I finished up my first GUI project that allows the user to open any PDF file by wither typing a product key, or manually find it using a tree view. I have all the files in the same folder as the application, the problem is that when I used pyinstaller to make it an .exe it wont pull up. and anytime I move it nothing pulls up because the code is linked to that specific location. my question is how do you write it to where the filepath is linked to a specific folder, and even if said folder moves, it still accesses those files?

```py
def Product_Look_UP():
    if inPro.get()== "24LPPS":
        Label(root, text= f"Searching for {inPro.get()}..." , fg = "Orange").grid(row = 3 , column = 0)
        import webbrowser as wb
        wb.open_new(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Product Finder\Data\Vender\vender\Ladder Pulls\24 in\Polished Stainless\LADDER PULL.pdf')
```

Essentially how do make `"C:\Users\user\Desktop"` be where ever the `"Product Finder"` folder is, whether it be on my computer, the server, or another persons computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the function `os.path.abspath` and pass it the file name of your main python script and it will return the path where the file is. You can do something like this:

```
import os
import webbrowser as wb

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
wb.open_new(f"{CURRENT_DIR}/data/test.pdf")
```